# Store an array into a txt file line by line PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file

I cannot figure out how to get the entire array stored into the txt file. My code only stores the last ran line in the foreach loop.

```
 $total_price = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
          $product_id = $product['product_id'];

          $total_price += $products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity'];
          echo "<tr>
            <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'><a href='./PA3.php?view_product=$id'>" . 
              $products[$product_id]['name'] . "</a></td>
            <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>$" . $products[$product_id]['price'] . "</td> 
            <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>" . $product['quantity'] . "</td>
            <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>$" . ($products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity']) . "</td>
            <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>" . $products[$product_id]['picture'] . "</td> 
          </tr>";
        }
      echo "</table>
      <p>Total price: $" . $total_price . "</p>";
      $filename='Order'.date('m-d-Y_hia').'.txt';
            file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($dataArray));  
  }
```

I think it is because I am initializing it inside of the array, but when I initialize it outside of it I get an index error.

Comment: the simplest route to take is, gather all the values first inside the container, after doing that, then write the file, don't try to write it line by line

Comment: you say "I think it is because I am initializing it inside of the array" wich is the variable? If is $dataArray in your code, you never initialize this var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 $filename='Order'.date('m-d-Y_hia').'.txt';

 $fh = fopen($filename, 'w');

  $total_price = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
      $product_id = $product['product_id'];

      $total_price += $products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity'];
      echo "<tr>
        <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'><a href='./PA3.php?view_product=$id'>" . 
          $products[$product_id]['name'] . "</a></td>
        <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>$" . $products[$product_id]['price'] . "</td> 
        <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>" . $product['quantity'] . "</td>
        <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>$" . ($products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity']) . "</td>
        <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>" . $products[$product_id]['picture'] . "</td> 
      </tr>";
    }
  echo "</table>
  <p>Total price: $" . $total_price . "</p>";


  foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {

     foreach($product as $k=>$v){

      $stringData = $k . ' - ' . $v . "\n";
       fwrite($fh, $stringData);

     }

  }

        //file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($dataArray));  
}


fclose($fh);
```

Comment: This works great, but it only stores the last values iterated through the first foreach loop

Comment: Sorry - was late last night when I added this. I updated my code. Check that out - it should work now.